# Cannot use browser on server PC

Tags: port, forwarding

I have a (Delphi-Indy based) custom server running on a dedicated PC. It used to listen on port 80 but on later versions of Windows that port is already assigned, so now I use port 8080.
My clients insist that HTTP traffic is on port 80. Therefor I instruct the LAN router to forward external traffic on port 80 to LAN port 8080 of the server PC.
This works fine.
However, now I cannot access internet via Chrome or IE on this server PC (which is a bit of a nuisance since for certain tasks, like checking upload speed, that would be helpful).
I sort of understand that: if these browsers get their response on external port 80, then the reponse will get to my server rather than the browser.
a) Am I correct with this explanation?
b) Is there a way to circumvent this conflict?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Nope, you're wrong. Browsers connect to remote port 80 (or any else), but opened local port is some random number between 1025-65535.

You should check firewall on your server to allow outgoing connections (or - and that is better way - don't browse internet from your server at all).

Comment: Apart from a single **or** I agree with everything you said. He should stop running a browser on the server **and** find out what is wrong with the firewall configuration. Having a firewall that behaves differently from your expectations is never a good idea.